# How to set a foreign key in OpenAPI with codegen?

Tags: jpa, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator

I am using OpenAPI Generator to generate the API for an application. For my models, I am using an OpenAPI definition that creates two models and APIs. My question is, how do I use JPA annotations correctly in my YAML? The YAML has the following body:

```yaml
perfil:
  type: object
  x-class-extra-annotation: "@javax.persistence.Entity"
  properties:
    codPerfil:
      type: integer
      x-field-extra-annotation: "@javax.persistence.Id"
      x-field-extra-annotation2: "@javax.persistence.OneToMany"
      example:
    descPerfil:
      type: string
      example:
    descPerfilEus:
      type: string
      example:
    documentacion:
      type: string
      example:
```

My main problem is that I need to use OneToMany and when I generate the database the foreign key is missing.

OpenAPI Generator settings:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>${springdoc-openapi-ui.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${swagger-annotations.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: What codegen do you use (Swagger Codegen, OpenAPI Generator, something else) and with which settings?

Comment: I use OpenAPI Generator with this settings                                                                     `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
   <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
   <version>${springdoc-openapi-ui.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
   <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
   <version>${swagger-annotations.version}</version>
  </dependency>`